# C++ Remote development IDE supporting shell scripts

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, makefile

We have a legacy C++ web application project which does not have a make file, instead there are a number of shell scripts which read parameters from txt file that build whole project or individual files along with their dependencies.

Is there a way can use any IDE (NETBEANS, ECLIPSE etc) which support C++ remote development on Linux(target), to build the project by running shell scripts rather than a make.

Is there any way we can modify the build process to allow us to use these existing scripts ?

Cheers,

Ash

Answer (score 1):

Most IDEs support "custom" targets or projects where you could write some custom commands to be executed when building. You could use that to have a script call the remote commands through SSH or similar techniques.

Comment: Thanks for your reply is there any examples how to do that for an existing project ?